# What is Avast! doing?

Tags: windows-8.1, avast

I have a few problems that have **only** happened since I installed Avast. I installed it 3 days ago:

- Chrome, when loading a new webpage, freezes my entire computer for about 1/4th a second.
- The amount of CPU power I have is reduced by about 20%. [image: http://puu.sh/7e91f.png]
- The icon [image] doesn't stop spinning. I'm not sure if this means it's doing something, but it seems like it.
- When I load a webpage, my speakers start making a crackling sound for about 1/2 a second while it's on and playing music. I tried 3 separate pairs of speakers.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with Avast!? It's the Internet Security version with Mail Shield and Antispam disabled.

It's fully updated to the latest version and definitions. I never had this problem with Malwarebytes, even with Realtime monitoring enabled. I've run a few scans and the CPU usage definitely went up (30%-ish usage). I uninstalled the browser plugin that came with it and have tried it while offline and it still does it. I've also tried re-installing it.

Comment: How long are you leaving it before you assume it's screwy?  Most anti-virus packages will be determined to do an update and a full system scan right after install, and that could take hours depending on your data. That would explain the icon and CPU usage In my mind.  If their update server are whacked out currently, it could be stuck waiting for and/or trying to process its responses. If it installs a browser plugin, it could be trying to pre-scan links for you.  Perhaps try installing it again, only unplug your Internet and see how it acts?

Comment: @Techie007 Added all that info to the post.

Comment: @Ramhound I uninstalled it completely. Nothing to disable.

Comment: @chipperyman573 - I missed that statement.  Have you tried to disable Chrome extension sync, backup your profile, delete your profile and verify the problem exists then?

Comment: is this issue only with chrome? what about a different browser?